# Filter Datatable column on primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

So, I have a very simple datatable that I want to filter, exacly like shown for the "Id" column of primeface's showcase: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml
I have a main file that has a  tag, which is supposed to call a second xhtml file that contains such datatable.
When the table is called from , the filter function doesn't work.
But when, instead of having , I just put the table inside the main file, IT WORKS. 
So to recap: called from , filter doesn't work. Otherwise, it does.
This is the (main) code for the main xhtml (it's not the entire file):

```
<p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:form id="contentPanel">
            <ui:include src="filteredTable.xhtml" />
            <!-- <p:dataTable var="chip" scrollable="true" id="checkboxDT"
                  filteredValue="#{dtBasicView.filteredChips}"
                  emptyMessage="No aggr found with given criteria"
                  value="#{dtBasicView.chips}">
                     <p:column filterBy="#{chip.callerId}"
                     filterMatchMode="contains">
                         <h:outputText value="#{chip.callerId}" />
                     </p:column>
                     <p:column headerText="Saldo">
                         <h:outputText value="#{chip.saldo} Mb" />
                     </p:column>
                </p:dataTable> -->                  
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>
```

The commented part is the content of "filteredTable.xhtml" (which is inside  tags). If I remove the comments, it works fine.

My question is: why, when I put the datatable inside , the filtering stops working? Is  not fit for this receiving this types of functionalities?

Comment: does it show any error ?!? i mean in the output.

Comment: Is the commented part the entire content of your filteredTable.xhtml? Where is your filteredTable.xhtml located? I could imagine that your src path is wrong. Try `<ui:include src="/WEB-INF/filteredTable.xhtml" />`

Comment: @YagamiLight No, it doesn't show any errors. The Datatable appears just fine, even the filter textfields. But when I type something inside it, nothing happens.

Comment: @chaeschuechli The datatable appears ok, so I guess it means the src is pointing to the right place. Could changing anything in the src be enough to make the filter function work?